# Write/saved logs in Wordpress

Tags: performance, logging

I´m doing a plugin which includes a query to import data from external API into custom post types/taxonomies/medias etc...
The query can be really heavy.
I had to make logs to know exactly what happens.
For the moment I´m saving logs thanks to `update_option()` to avoid loose logs when I have these kinds of errors :

- 503 Service Unavailable errors
- timeout server error
- php errors
  etc...
  But, I got a new error :

> mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused

Maybe because there are too many action with the database.
I changed `define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');` by `define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');` without any success.

If I´m using a log file, I will have to open/write/close the log file all the time and the algorithme would need more time. That could create a timeout server error.

What could be the best way in my case ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend doing large bulk updates to the database like big imports or exports outside of the Wordpress codebase as much as possible because of issues like this, **but only if this makes sense for your code and you're able to maintain the wordpress data structures**

If the logging information is just to see what happens with this operation and you don't need it after or to see it in Wordpress, then `update_option` is definitely not a great solution. Opening a file, or writing to your own table would be better.

There's no reason not to write a PHP script which opens a single connection to the database to do its work, a single file for logging and does what it needs to do.

Or, if you want to take advantage of some Wordpress calls, then use [wp-cli's eval-file](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/eval-file/) to run a script which will give you access to those.

For tasks like this if you don't already have it then access to the command line, e.g. through ssh will make your life a lot easier and save you tons of time. This approach may also give you much easier access to error messages.

For more help with the specific thing you're doing more details on the heavy query you're running would help. Connection refused and those other errors could be caused by a lot of things, but your approach of having logging somewhere is a good one, as long as it helps to diagnose problems and retry the rest of the work.